# Setting global Java options in Bash

Tags: java, linux, bash

I want to pass `-Dtangosol.coherence.wka=localhost` to the JAVA options.

When I was trying `java -Dtangosol.coherence.wka=localhost -jar myapp.jar`, it works. The flag successfully passed into the application.

But, I want to use bash script to set the flag into the JAVA global variable, so I don't need to pass the flag every time running the application.

I tried:

`export JAVA_OPTS="-Dtangosol.coherence.wka=localhost"`
But, it seems doesn't work. Did I missing something?

Comment: ...that said, JAVA_OPTS is generally honored by _shell scripts starting Java_, not by the JVM itself. If you haven't written such a script, there's nothing to pay attention to it, so it can't be expected to have any effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I confused JVM option and JAVA options. Actually, the I parameter I was passing is JVM option. Is there a way to set it up through bash?

Comment: (Also, it's frankly bad practice; I'm not sure which major OSS project -- maybe Tomcat? -- is to blame for starting the `JAVA_OPTS` trend, but the way it's used means that only a very restricted subset of values can be passed that way, for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)... unless it's invoked with `eval`, which creates a new/different/additional set of bugs, some of them security-impacting).

Comment: Honestly, the easiest thing to do here is just to build your own wrapper for your app. As a shell function, `myapp() { java -Dtangosol.coherence.wka=localhost -jar myapp.jar "$@"; }` will create a `myapp` command that adds that value to the command line, and also passes through any arguments given to the function to the underlying command. As an executable file named `myapp`, you'd need just two lines -- `#!/bin/sh` and then `java -Dtangosol.coherence.wka=localhost -jar myapp.jar "$@"` -- to do the same.

Comment: It's Helidon(Micro-service project) running in Docker. The original problem is that I need to pass different JVM options for different environment (development, QA, etc..). The docker file doesn't support for conditional statement. So, I have to execute a bash script in DockerFile to determine the right environment.. In the bash script, I am aiming to setup some global jvm options depending on the environment.. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: You can use conditionals in Dockerfiles if you're clever about it. Anything you can do in sh, you can do in the `...` part of `RUN ["sh", "-c", "..."]`.

Comment: ...so, let's say your Dockerfile has a line `ENV environment=dev`; you can later `RUN ["sh", "-c", "case $environment in dev) target=localhost;; prod=target=foo.example.com;; *) echo 'Error: Unknown environment' >&2; exit 1;; esac; exec java -Dtangosol.coherence.wka=\"$target\" \"$@\"", "_", "other arguments go here and later"]`

Comment: Granted, that's a bit grotty, but that's why I suggested creating a script -- you can `COPY` that script into your Docker image.

Comment: Thanks, I am confused by that script.. Currently, I have `ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]`. I want to execute `-Dtangosol.coherence.wka=localhost` only when the $environment=dev. Can I simply modify my code to achieve that?

Comment: nvm thanks, I got it.!